# How is gl_PrimitiveID interpreted in Tessellation Control and Evaluation shaders?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4, tesselation

#### The OpenGL spec. says:

> The variable **`gl_PrimitiveID`** is filled with the number of primitives processed
>   by the drawing command which generated the input vertices. The first primitive generated by a drawing command is numbered zero, and the primitive ID counter is incremented after every individual point, line, or triangle primitive is processed. Restarting a primitive topology using the primitive restart index has no effect on the primitive ID counter.

Unfortunately, I do not quite understand that.

If I make a draw call with `GL_PATCHES` with number of vertices = **32**, do all **32** vertices have `gl_PrimitiveID` = **0** in the Tesselation Control shader?

*Tessellation Control shaders still output a Patch, and a Patch is a single primitive.*

Is it correct to assume that when this patch is tessellated as triangles in the Tessellation Evaluation shader, every n<sup>th</sup> vertex will have its `gl_PrimitiveID` = **<sup>n</sup>/<sub>3</sub>**?

If not, please explain what their values will be.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL wiki [seems to agree](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader):

> **gl_PrimitiveID​**
>
> the index of the current patch within this rendering command.

Looking this up in spec shouldn't be hard, if you need confirmation.

I guess the number of patch within the rendering command would change simply when you process enough vertices and start a new patch.

Comment: It is my understanding that (cannot test this right now) the patch primitive ID will be incremented after every n-many vertices are processed, where n is the number of vertices the user defines a patch as having. So if you draw 64 vertices and you define your patch primitive to have 32, then half of the patch vertices would belong to `gl_PrimitiveID` 0 and the other half to `gl_PrimitiveID` 1. You should not need anything fancier than that to increase the primitive ID using a regular draw call.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman uh.. I feel embarrased, but yes, I think that you're right! Brain freeze or whatever.